# Display post Data in a Bootstrap Modal in Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to Display data in a Modal from a Post Request to my Django backend.

```
$(function (e) {
  $(".form-select").change(function (event) {
    let $vid = this.value;
    let $hostname =$(this).closest('tr').find('td.hostname').text(); 
    for(var i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++){ //deselect the option
          this.options[i].selected = false;
        }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/api/vulinfo',
        data: {
          'client': $hostname,
          'vid' : $vid,
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
        },
        success: function(response) {
          $('#vulmodal').modal("show");
        
      }
    
    });
  });
```

The correct `hostname` and `vid` is send to my Django View.

```
def vulInfo(request):
    qs = clientvul.objects.all().filter(client=request.POST['client']).filter(VID=request.POST['vid'])
    return render(request,'browseDB.html', {'vuldata':qs}, status=200)
```

I try to access the Data in the Modal, but it´s always empty

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="vulmodal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <h1>Path:{{vuldata.path}} </h1>
            text text text
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class client(models.Model):
    client= models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    user= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vuls = models.ManyToManyField(
        'vul',
        through='clientvul',
        related_name='client'
    )
    
 
class vul(models.Model):
    vid=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    cvelist=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cvsscore=models.FloatField(max_length=5)
    serverity=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    summary=models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class clientvul(models.Model):
    
    client= models.ForeignKey(client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vid=models.ForeignKey(vul, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    path=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    isActive=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
               fields=['client', 'VID'], name='unique_migration_host_combination' # legt client und VID als Primarykey fest
            )
        ]



admin.site.register(client)
admin.site.register(vul)
admin.site.register(clientvul)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the value "path" in your h1:

Path:{{vuldata.Path}}

But in your clientvul model, it is written with p in lowercase so you can make that change: Path:{{vuldata.path}}

Comment: sorry it was an typo in the Question. Does not fix the Modal